# Which map should I use for my requirement?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have two requirements and i can only use map.

1. Duplicate keys are allowed.(for this i am using multimap)
2. I have to search for a wild card. 
   Example : if keyset contains "Dave" and "Dave bautista" it will return both.

How to achieve both?

Comment: From what you wrote I can just say you should use the search field as the map value, not the keys. So you could have duplicate and implement such a search with wild cards. Anyway, your post is off topic here as you don't have a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Returning Map
    Map<String, Object> filterObjects = new HashedMap();

    // Input List Map
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashedMap();
    map.put("Dave", null);
    map.put("Dave bautista", null);

    // User requesting Key Name
    String userInput = "Dave bautista";

    for (int i = 0; i < map.keySet().size(); i++) {
        //KeyNames retrieve as element by element from the map
        String keyName = map.keySet().toArray()[i].toString();

        //checks the availability of the userInput with element name
        if (keyName.contains(userInput)) {
            // If matched, then put it in to the return Map
            filterObjects.put(keyName, map.get(keyName));
        }

    }

    return filterObjects;
```